# Determine if new request or editing an existing record

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a login page that authenticates to AD, works great. After login there is a page for a service request, user can save their request and return to it later to finish or submit it if it's done. These 2 actions set a flag in the record (saved or submitted). When a user logs in, I can present them with a list of their saved requests. Now, if they click on a saved request link, I can pass the record ID via the URL.... but then I get stuck.
Should I have a different page for editing/updating records, or should I use the new request page again? If I use the same page, what's the best way to do that? My impression is that there would be a lot of "if...returning...else", making the code difficult to read. On the other hand... if I do 2 pages, any change or update needs to go in both.
I'm using VS2010 and EF4. First project in this environment, don't know what's best practice here.

Comment: Are you using webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of reusing the page; there is some if/else, but not all over the place.  For instance, when updating an entity, you can do:

```
SomeEntity entity;
bool adding = false;

if (key > 0)
   entity = db.Entities.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Key == key);
if (entity == null)
{
   entity = new SomeEntity { initialvalue = "X" };
   adding = true;
}

entity.Z = someValue;
//set other props

if (adding)
   db.Entities.AddObject(entity);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

As far as the UI is concerned, yes there is some showing/hiding, but effort-wise there will be less.

Comment: The UI is concerning. In PHP I would say "If this exists then value=''". I'm not seeing how to do that here. Any suggestions, examples or links?

Comment: Oh, all the fields are populated from the code behind! Right?

Comment: Yes this is all done in code.  This is nice because it separates the presentation from the logic.